# Is this snippet of code following all the best practices? The code is intended to capitalize the first letter of a word

Tags: c++, performance

How can I improve this so that it follows all the best practices?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string userInput{ " " };
  std::cin >> userInput;

  if( int( userInput[ 0 ] ) > 96 && int( userInput[ 0 ] ) < 123  )
  {
    userInput[ 0 ] = char( int( userInput[ 0 ] ) - 32 );
  }

  std::cout << userInput << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

32,96 and 123 used are ascii character codes.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: Code Review requires sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Thanks,i've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your code can and should be improved:

1. You are missing the include for `std::string`.
2. Default-constructing the string is sufficient.
3. You fail to check whether reading from `std::cin` succeeded.
4. Converting a `char` to `int` before comparison with `int` constants has no effect.
   If any of the values compared against were outside the common range of `char` and `unsigned char` (a minimum of 0 to 127 inclusive), conversion to `unsigned char` would have an effect.
5. Use character-literals for respective constants. While the portability concerns for character codes are largely academic as long as you restrict yourself to ASCII, it's still needless obfuscation. Also, in this case a close range would be appropriate.
6. Writing your own `toupper()` might be cute, but that implementation is restricted to pure ASCII. The true `toupper()` is restricted to SBCSs (no unicode), which might suffice for a toy-program.
7. `return 0;` is implied for `main()`.

Fixed code:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    if (!(std::cin >> input)) {
        std::cerr << "Could not read from STDIN.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    input[0] = std::toupper((unsigned char)input[0]);
    std::cout << input << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for  the information it was very helpful @Deduplicator

Comment: You should use `static_cast<unsigned char>` instead of the c-style cast. :-p

Comment: @jdt Some think the traditional cast should always be avoided, others only in not completely obvious situations... Ah well.